# $\prod\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{3a_i+2}{2a_i+1}, a_i\geq 1$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, reference-request

$$\prod\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{3a_i+2}{2a_i+1},
a_i\geq 1$$
Claim: This product is never an integer ($a_i$ integer).

Comment: $$2(3x+2)-3(2x+1)=?$$

Comment: 2(3x+2)−3(2x+1)=1, I dont see it? It only shows its not possible for n=1?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity

Comment: I dont get how I can apply this to n>1!

Comment: A tag is 'elementary' number theory. I don't find this problem elementary at all...

Comment: it is, instead. Give me a minute

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's false:
$$
\frac{29}{19}\frac{38}{25}\frac{44}{29}\frac{83}{55}\frac{125}{83}=8
$$

Comment: How did you find it? Have you used a program?

Comment: No, I wrote them by hand until 125/83 and discarded those with $a\equiv 1(3)$

Comment: How did you do this? Did you see that it isnt true from the start?(how?)

Comment: It just looked too strange to me that it was true.. I knew that going far I'd find something that simplified.. Now that I'm thinking about it, maybe I can find something better..

Comment: Wow!!! Is there an intuitive argument for why the statement isnt true? Or maybe a better question why your counterexample is in fact a counterexample?

Comment: $n=5$, $a_i=9,12,14,27,41$ generate my counterexample. You can test it by yourself. Intuitively, there exist $x$ such that $3x+2$ is divisible by any prime bigger than 3, so we have a lot of freedom in choosing $a_i$

Comment: I've ment is there a way to find these $a_i tuples$ (other than bruteforce)? Or to explain why they exist? Hm... That argument isnt intuitive enough for me, as it doesnt use some relation of $3x+2$ and $2x+1$. Is the product always a power of 2?

Answer (score 4):

Some more counterexamples: 
$$ \frac{20}{13} \frac{ 38}{25} \frac{ 83}{55} \frac{ 125}{83} \frac{143}{95} = 8$$

$$\frac{8}{5}{\frac {65}{43}}{\frac {74}{49}}{\frac {83}{55}}{\frac {98}{65
}}{\frac {125}{83}}{\frac {143}{95}}{\frac {209}{139}}{\frac {215}
{143}}{\frac {278}{185}}=64$$

$${\frac {11}{7}}{\frac {38}{25}}{\frac {65}{43}}{\frac {83}{55}}{
\frac {98}{65}}{\frac {125}{83}}{\frac {143}{95}}{\frac {215}{143}}
=28$$

$${\frac {17}{11}}{\frac {20}{13}}{\frac {26}{17}}{\frac {74}{49}}{
\frac {83}{55}}{\frac {98}{65}}{\frac {125}{83}}{\frac {143}{95}}{
\frac {209}{139}}{\frac {278}{185}}=64$$

EDIT:
In general, given a finite set of fractions $f_j$, consider the set $P$ of primes
that divide their denominators.  If the [$p$-adic order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order) of $f_j$ is $\nu_p(f_j)$,
the condition for $\prod_j f_j$ to be an integer is $\sum_j \nu_p(f_j) \ge 0$
for all $p \in P$.  Let $x_j$ be binary variables (i.e. possible values $0$ and $1$).  Then $\prod_j f_j^{x_j}$ is an integer iff $\sum_j \nu_p(f_j)\; x_j \ge 0$ for all $p \in P$.  So what we want to do is find  solutions to the
system of linear inequalities
$$ \sum_j \nu_p(f_j)\; x_j \ge 0, \ p \in P $$
$$ \sum_j x_j \ge 1 $$
$$ x_j \in \{0,1\}$$
Integer linear programming software can be used for this (I used the Optimization package in Maple).

Comment: are you using a program, or using some algorithm?

Comment: How are you getting those examples? Are you bruteforcing? Or is there some pattern?